# Humming noise coming from our light, exhaust fan, Bluetooth combo unit

Tags: bathroom

There is a humming noise combing from our exhaust fan, light, Bluetooth combo unit.

It happens all the time even when I turn it off

Answer (score 1):

Presumably one of the lower quality Asian sources, and if it has Bluetooth it's never fully off, so likely a poor quality noisy power supply for that part.

*Why* a fan needs Bluetooth is a mystery to me, or marketing fertilizer that I'm immune to.

If it has a warranty, get it replaced. If not, replace it and look for something better when replacing it.

Comment: Bluetooth allows a "smart" house to turn on the fan, e.g. when you take a phone into the bathroom or turn on the gas range (depending on what type of exhaust fan it is).  Note:  you may reasonably prefer a manual, physical switch for either of those, but that's the kind of thing that "smart" houses do.  Everything should be linked to everything else.